# "И всё-таки() в чём тут дело?"

Tags: пунктуация, интонация

Какой знак препинания лучше всего подходит? Понятно, что при прочтении без пауз с ударением на *"чём"* знаков препинания не нужно. *А если акцент на "всё-таки": "и всЁ-таки!"?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В справочнике по пунктуации от "Грамоты" есть статья, допускающая интонационную *запятую* после "всё-таки" в начале предложения:

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_115

Можно взглянуть на выбор знака и иначе, поскольку в разных контекстах такое начало предложения можно трактовать как *сокращение* (до частицы "всё-таки") от разных вариантов вступления:

1) И всё-таки (хотелось бы знать),

2) И всё-таки (скажите/ответьте):

3) И всё-таки (давайте разберёмся) —

Первое характерно для нейтральной просьбы уточнить что-то (запятая). Во втором случае вопрос задаётся с пристрастием (хочется оставить двоеточие перед содержанием вопроса). Третье характерно как форма привлечения внимания аудитории или читателей (можно бы и тире поставить). Но пунктуация - сложившаяся система условностей, поэтому варианты, отличные от запятой, видимо, возможны лишь в порядке авторской вольности.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Мне нравятся Ваши варианты, а также нравится, что Грамота разбирает этот случай.